# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 - route-me library, ad hoc only

Tags: ipad, xcode4.3, adhoc, ios5.1, route-me

I have read through all of the other questions related to this topic, and can not find my answer.  My project is using route-me.  It builds just fine for the simulator, and for a connected iPad.  The archive for ad hoc will not build.  I had successfully produced an ad hoc archive - and installed it - prior to implementing route-me.  My error is:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>
> "_ApplicationVersion", referenced from:
>        -[RMWebTileImage startLoading:] in libMapView.a(RMWebTileImage.o)
>    "_ApplicationNameFromBundle", referenced from:
>        -[RMWebTileImage startLoading:] in libMapView.a(RMWebTileImage.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

My library is properly linked - it builds for simulator and iPad error free. I do have

> [RMMapView class];

in the view controller that is displaying the map.  Prior to having that line, my app would crash if installed from the archive with iTunes - although it would not crash if installed from Xcode.  Now the archive will not build at all.  (But I still believe the above line has put me on the right path).

I have tried every solution that might apply that I have been able to find here. If I remove the references to RMWebTileImage.h and RMWebTileImage.m - I get the same errors, except then it makes sense.  But when I add the references back in, I still get the error, as if the files were not even referenced.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the static library of route-me does not have the armv7 symbols. Check the build settings of the library and make sure the architectures build settings are set to build for armv6 and armv7.

You also always can use `lipo -info` on your static library to see all the included architectures.

If you are linking the Debug configuration, this is mostly set to build for active architectures only. Make sure the projects build settings are identical to the route-me project settings.